# Function that return value or a function

Tags: javascript

How could I make a function that I can call its result multiple times but still get its value when I stop ?

For example -

```
add(2)(3) // 5
add(2)(3)(6) // 11
```

How should I implement the `add` to get it ?

Comment: Can you please add your attempt to the question?

Comment: Use `arguments` inside the function and call it like `add(2,3,4,5....)`

Comment: It's not possible. It needs to always return a function, but that function can have valueOf and toString properties or better, a Symbol.toPrimitive property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible if you consume the value somehow. You'd need to implement custom `valueOf` and/or `toString` methods depending on the usage.

But keep in mind the value is still a function. If you do `typeof add(1)` you'll get `"function"`

```js
const add = value => {
  const next = sum => add(value + sum)
  
  next.valueOf = next.toString = function() {
    return value;
  }
 
  
  return next
}

console.log(add(1), add(1)(2), add(1)(2)(3))

console.log(typeof add(1)(2))
```

Comment: what kind of sorcery is this!!

Comment: @Hith Dark interview magic. I doubt this is useful in production code :). Though in general `valueOf` and `toString` (and es2015 `Symbol.toPrimitive`) are quite handy esp if you are into OOP.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can do this due to the nature of closures. Return a function from your previous function call. Something like this:

```js
//add(2)(3) // 5
//add(2)(3)(6) // 11

function add2(a) {
  var i = a;
  return function(b) {
    i += b;
    return i;
  };
}

function add3(a) {
  var i = a;
  return function(b) {
    i += b;
    return function(c) {
      i += c;
      return i;
    }
  };
}

console.log(add2(2)(3));
console.log(add3(2)(3)(6));
```